# pass the form by POST method with jQuery load()

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I want to pass data as POST instead of GET 
How can I change this line of code to pass the form by POST method?

> var data = form.serialize();

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> Form</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#itm_form").submit(function(evento){
      evento.preventDefault();
      var form = jQuery(this);
      // When using an object/map (key/value pairs), the request is made as a POST.
      var data = form.serialize();
      jQuery('#destino').load("recibe-parametros3.php", data, function(){   // load(url, data, complete);
         alert("recibidos los datos por ajax");
      }); 
   });

}) 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="itm_form" >
Nombre: <input type="text" name="itm_name">
Email: <input type="text" name="itm_email">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
<input type="hidden" name="itm_oculto" value="0">

</form>
<div id="destino"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/): `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`

Comment: if your data variable is an object, it should use post instead of get. So your code seems correct.

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault the `serialize()` method returns a string, not an object.

Comment: He could use `JSON.parse()` on the string, though.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery

Comment: Finally i tried an alternative solution instead of load I use the POST method directly. Which actually works!    ** jQuery.post("recibe-parametros.php" , jQuery(form).serialize() ,function(data){
 alert(data);  });